# nginx & letsencrypt - end of file, expecting ";" or "}"

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

I want to setup nginx with my docker-compose on my domain name *vip-75.com* but I keep having this issue and I don't see where my `nginx.conf` file is incorrect:

> [emerg] 1#1: unexpected end of file, expecting ";" or "}" in
>   /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf:2

Below is my `nginx.conf` file:

```
worker_processes 1;
events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    sendfile on;
    upstream shinyproxy {
        server shinyproxy:8080;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name vip-75.com;
        server_tokens off;

        location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            root /var/www/certbot;
        }

        location / {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name vip-75.com;
        server_tokens off;



        ssl_certificate       /etc/letsencrypt/live/vip-75.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key   /etc/letsencrypt/live/vip-75.com/privkey.pem;
        include               /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        ssl_dhparam           /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://shinyproxy;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_read_timeout 600s;
            proxy_buffering    off;

            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT1**:
I see *404 Not Found* in `/home/ec2-user/data/certbot/conf/options-ssl-nginx.conf`
But no folder `letsencrypt/` or file `options-ssl-nginx.conf` in `etc/`folder.
The tutorial I followed is [Nginx and Let’s Encrypt with Docker in Less Than 5 Minutes](https://medium.com/@pentacent/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71)

Comment: What's in /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf ?

Comment: hi Alister, just edited my post regarding your comment.Thx.